# d3.js and dashcode: anyone tried and won?

Tags: macos, d3.js, dashcode

I'd like to build OSX widgets to rapidly prototype streaming-data-based viz dashboard components. I'd like to use d3.js to do that displaying, but the most basic things I try get stuck with errors I have no ability / patience to parse.

Before I start wasting time on this, I was wondering if anyone's already trod this ground and won or lost? If you won, how did you do it? If you lost, did you understand why?

Comment: I've just noticed the mixed metaphor. Sorry.

Comment: do you have any sample code to play with?

Answer (score 2):

OK so it turns out the answer to this question is that it's totally possible and quite rewarding! Just be sure to turn on the "this widget can access the internet" option to avoid really confusing errors.